# Python Pandas: Change a value in pd1 based of pd2 with a different name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 data frames where the index is the same value but different name. I need to add a column to DF1 but get that information from DF2

```
DF1:
    SKU       X        Y         Z      
    1234      0        0         0
    5642      0        0         0

DF2:
    AH SKU     X        Y         Z      Total
    1234      4        5         1        10
    5642      1        0         1         2
```

So I know I can add the total column to DF1 by doing

```
df1 ["Total"]
```

How can I now have that `total` from DF2 to DF1 making sure the `SKU` and `AH SKU` are matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it like this, using default index matching.

```py
df1["Total"] = df2["Total"]
```

That the indexes have different names shouldn't matter in this case (there's only one index level).

Make sure that those "columns" you pointed to in the answer really are the index: print(df1.index) should have something named SKU, and so on.

Comment: what if ```SKU``` and ```AH SKU``` are not in the same order in the files ?

Comment: Did you try it? It was said in the question that those are the indexes. Pandas aligns by index when you assign values. Order doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes i just tired it but i jusrt wanted to make sure thats all Im new to pandas :)

Comment: Great. As James Powell claims, understanding how index/indexes work in pandas is the best foundation for using pandas. From https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjq3QOxl9Ok